# ruby : NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have the following problem

i have the following association between user and role models

```
# User
has_many :memberships
has_many :roles , :through =>  :memberships

# Role
has_many :memberships
has_many :users , :through =>  :memberships
```

and i have bridge caled membership as you can guess 
it have

```
# Membership
belongs_to user
belongs_to role
```

the problem is when i try to create new user i have this method that i call it in before_create

```
before_create :build_role

def build_role
  memberships.build
end
```

it gives me

> uninitialized constant User::Membership

what should i do to overcome this?

Comment: Can you post the model for Membership and preferably the other models too?

Comment: You can't build a membership in a before_create: before_create is a hook to call methods before the object is created in the DB (= received an ID), and building an object through a relation need this id to refer to the object. Try putting this buid_role in an after_create instead, and try to use `self.memberships.build`

Comment: doesn't work that way also

Comment: Where is your Membership class defined (name of the file and location). Also I am assuming that missing colons at Memebrship's belongs_to are just a typo?

Comment: class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base 
file name : membership.rb inside models dir

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the class name explicitly in your association definition

```
has_many :memberships, :class_name => "Membership"
has_many :roles , :through =>  :memberships
```

Generally its not needed if you follow the naming convention for associations. It may be because you have your models namespaced.

Comment: yes same error exactly also tried @MrYoshiji approach but no use

Comment: Did you try it the explicit way? `has_many ... class_name: "::Membership"` If that works you may have fallen into a lookup fallacy (as I did recently)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem… totally my fault. In `Membership`, it should be

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :role
```

I left out the colons.

Comment: AH, so it was not a typo. However I wonder why you didn't get other error instead, like `undefined variable 'user' for class Membership` or similar.

Comment: `Membership` class fails to load because of this error. So `User` class doesn't know what `Membership` is